# How to make variables go inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

i got in one scope this function:

```
AjaxState.prototype.run_on_finish = function(callback){
    if (this.isRunning()){
        setTimeout('AjaxState.obj().run_on_finish('+callback+')', 250);
    }else{
        callback();
    }
}
```

i just check if all ajax was finished and then after i call the callback (if all ajax is finished)...
but, at other point i try to use this function calling like this:

//.obj() is just to call the singleton patter.

```
function foo(){
 var id = 2;
 AjaxState.obj().run_on_finish(function(){
  makeThings(id);
 });
}();
```

when i execute this, i receive the msg "id is not defined" because i think that "run_on_finish" just look for it in global scope, if i remove "var" from id, it works... but i don't want to make it global, i want to send it throught the function, is that possible?

Comment: Hilarious question title `:)`

Comment: The whole `run_on_finish` thing makes no sense at all. Why are you not using event-based callbacks, i.e. hook the `readystatechange` event?

Comment: Your example must be incomplete. Provide the real code. In the example you've given, `id` is effectively closed into the `run_on_finish` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function foo() {
var id = 2;
    AjaxState.obj().run_on_finish(
      (function(id) {
        var sub_id = id;
        return function() {
          makeThings(id);
        };
      })(id));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/cGCBh/6/

Comment: What's the purpose of this extra closure?

Comment: @katspaugh to get id from the parent function foo into the function that's passed into `run_on_finish`. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: @katspaugh consider adding your own answer then :)